# excel vba: Range gives Argument Not Optional error message

Tags: excel, vba, range

In excel vba I'm tryin to select a range of values starting in Cell"O2", (O from Oyster) down to the end of the sheet,
I'm trying:

```
 Range("O2", Range.End(xlDown))
```

But that fails with `Argument Not Optional`. What am i doing wrong?
I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `xlDown` Declare your Objects and then work with it.

Use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col O which has data
        LRow = .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> This is your range
        Set rng = .Range("O2:O" & LRow)

        With rng
            '~~> Whatever you want to do
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

To select the range from O2 to the last filled cell in that column, you could use:

```
Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Select
```

But that has a few problems, including the fact that it will "stop" at any blanks, and that you should [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) unless absolutely necessary. Also, you should get in the habit of qualifying your ranges, e.g., specifying which worksheet they're in. Given all that, I propose something like this, assuming you wanted to turn the cells in the range red:

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    LastRow = .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Interior.Color = vbRed
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 :) The other problem with `xldown` is that if `O2` is the only cell which has data then `xldown` will select the entire range up till the end of Excel rows.

Comment: That's true. +1 to you too. Looks like I was almost as fast ;).

Comment: Your Triple hat is slowing you down :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need

```
Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Select
```

?